# How to Scan an Image using Interop.WIA in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to scan an Image using Interop.WIA in a WPF app. I downloaded the below class code but `constants` has a error? I added Interop.WIA.dll.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using WIA;

namespace WPF_Example.Services
{
    public class ScannerService
    {
        public static void Scan()
        {
            try
            {
                CommonDialogClass commonDialogClass = new CommonDialogClass();
                Device scannerDevice = commonDialogClass.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, false, false);
                if (scannerDevice != null)
                {
                    Item scannnerItem = scannerDevice.Items[1];
                    AdjustScannerSettings(scannnerItem, 600, 0, 0, 1010, 620, 0, 0);
                    object scanResult = commonDialogClass.ShowTransfer(scannnerItem, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, false);
                    if (scanResult != null)
                    {
                        ImageFile image = (ImageFile)scanResult;
                        SaveImageToJpgFile(image, Constants.ScannedImageLocation);
                     }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem with scanning device. Please ensure that the scanner is properly connected and switched on", "Inweon Grain Management System");
            }
        }

        private static void AdjustScannerSettings(IItem scannnerItem, int scanResolutionDPI, int scanStartLeftPixel, int scanStartTopPixel,
            int scanWidthPixels, int scanHeightPixels, int brightnessPercents, int contrastPercents)
        {
            const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6147";
            const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6148";
            const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6149";
            const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6150";
            const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6151";
            const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6152";
            const string WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS = "6154";
            const string WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS = "6155";
            const string WIA_SCAN_BIT_DEPTH = "4104";
            SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI, scanResolutionDPI);
            SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI, scanResolutionDPI);
            SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL, scanStartLeftPixel);
            SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL, scanStartTopPixel);
            //SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_BIT_DEPTH, 48);
            SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS, brightnessPercents);
            SetWIAProperty(scannnerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS, contrastPercents);
        }

        private static void SetWIAProperty(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
        {
            Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
            prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
        }

        private static void SaveImageToJpgFile(ImageFile image, string fileName)
        {
            ImageProcess imgProcess = new ImageProcess();
            object convertFilter = "Convert";
            string convertFilterID = imgProcess.FilterInfos.get_Item(ref convertFilter).FilterID;
            imgProcess.Filters.Add(convertFilterID, 0);
            SetWIAProperty(imgProcess.Filters[imgProcess.Filters.Count].Properties, "FormatID", WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG);
            image = imgProcess.Apply(image);
            image.SaveFile(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

The error text is `The name 'Constants' does not exist in the current context`
in other words I want when I click on button the image is scanned by scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the errors message is pretty clear, isn't it?

It says `Constants` does not exist. But you are using it as a parameter to `SaveImageToJpgFile`. So either add the missing file where those constants are defined, add the missing using statement to the namespace where the constants class is defined or remove the `Constants` stuff and hard-code a path where your scanned images should be saved.
Like This:

`SaveImageToJpgFile(image, @"C:\Users\[your-user-name]\Pictures");`

EDIT:
I think you have to provide a valid filename instead of a directory name, so you have generate a new name for each file if you don't want to overwrite previously scanned files.

`SaveImageToJpgFile(image, @"C:\Users\[your-user-name]\Pictures\img001.jpg");`